# What is write protection in flash/EEPROM memory?

Tags: microcontroller, flash-memory

I'm pretty new in microcontroller area. For my project, I was told to implement a write/read function for writing/reading data from Flash/EEPROM memory. 
I did a quick search and saw some terminologies like: "***Write protection***", "***Flash page***", "**Protected flash page**". What are these really mean? When and why do we need these "write protection" or " protected flash page" ?

Thanks,
Bien

Comment: Read the words, and try to think why you might need them. What would you expect *write protection* to mean? I read it as *protection against being written to*, and an educated guess would be that you use it when you don't want anything to be able to write to that memory. Now apply the same logic to *Protected flash page*.

Answer (score 1):

Eeprom and flash and other roms are implemented with pages, blobs of bits that all erase in one action.  You can typically only erase whole pages at a time.   Normally they erase to all ones, but some are the other way around, for the erase to all one case, you can think of it this way the only way to "write" ones is to erase a page, but you can write zeros on a essentially a bit by bit basis. (by writing a byte or whatever the smallest write is and only changing the zeros you want).

write protection means just what it says, writing protecting the whole part, or fractions of the part or a page by page basis as per the design.

sometimes the write protection uses pins being pulled high or low or the pins protect the ability to unlock things after being locked.  again it is on a design by design, vendor by vendor basis as to what features are there, and you simply read the docs and experiment.

Comment: Thanks alot @dwelch.